# validate part of form yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have a wizard form in my yii2 project. My form is type of yii2 active form.
Now I want to validate each part separately. for example first section of wizard includes `t1`, `t2`, `t3` and second section includes `t4`, `t5`. when user click the next step button of section 1 I want just verify `t1`, `t2` and `t3` but not `t4` and `t5`. How should I do this in yii2?

**Edit**

Please notice that I want use yii2 validator and don't want to write validation rules in my jquery code again.

**Edit: Please check the code**

```
$wizard_config = [
    'id' => 'stepwizard',
    'steps' => [
        1 => [
            'title' => 'اطلاعات پروژه',
            'icon' => 'fa fa-info',
            'content' =>
                $form->field($model, 'title') .
                $form->field($model, 'language_id')->dropDownList($language, ['style' => 'padding-top: 0;', 'prompt' => 'زبان']) .
                $form->field($model, 'project_type_id')->dropDownList($project_type, ['style' => 'padding-top: 0;']) .
                $form->field($model, 'text_type_id')->dropDownList($text_type, ['style' => 'padding-top: 0;']) .
                $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['style'=>'height: 140px;resize:none;'])
            ,

        ],
        2 => [
            'title' => 'فایل های پروژه',
            'icon' => 'fa fa-upload',
            'content' =>
                $form->field($model, 'proj_file')->fileInput() .
                $form->field($model, 'pages') .
                $form->field($model, 'template')->fileInput()
            ,
        ],
        3 => [
            'title' => 'زمان و قیمت',
            'icon' => 'fa fa-clock-o',
            'content' =>
                $form->field($model, 'deadline_day') .
                $form->field($model, 'deadline_time') .
                $form->field($model, 'doing_way_id') .
                $form->field($model, 'user_id') .
                $form->field($model, 'pawn_money') .
                $form->field($model, 'is_group')
            ,
        ],
        4 => [
            'title' => 'تایید',
            'icon' => 'fa fa-check',
            'content' => '<h3>Step 3</h3>This is step 3',
        ],
    ],
    'start_step' => 1,
];
```

Comment: i think you need to take t1,t2,t3 in different div and t4,t5 in different div and validate as per div

Comment: I have did this buddy. Please explain more about your solution. @jilesh

Comment: Please paste your code @BehzadHassani .

Comment: @NanaPartykar please check the update

Comment: You are using a single active form or an active form for each single step?

Comment: No Buddy @scaisEdge I use an activeForm at the beginning of the wizard

Comment: and for validate every single step how you think to do. Given you don't want use jquery and (i think) ajax validation?

Comment: @scaisEdge I want use jquery buddy but want to rewrite the rules. for example in MVC.NET we can validate every input separately. Does yii do same?

Comment: there is an extension available with the name [`yii2-formwizard`](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. Many thanks to `Amin Cheloh` and `Alexander Makarov` providing [this](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/forms-activeform-js.md) article.
for validating just one input of form. we should use this one line code.

```
$('#id-of-form').yiiActiveForm('validateAttribute', 'input id');
```

Comment: This is only client side validation. You still need to perform validation on server side for security,

Comment: yes we can use scenario for ajax validation. It was main problem of this question @arogachev

Comment: concise and perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

You can separate steps in model for different scenarios.

```
 public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();

    $scenarios['step1'] = ['login', 'username'];
    $scenarios['step2'] = ['t1', t2];

    return $scenarios;
}
```

Then assign scenario for model in each steps

```
 $user->scenario = 'step1';
```

and validate only part of model's attributes. You have to write ajax action, that can map step and scenario and return validation result.